# Does using uiRecordApi in lwc count towards salesforce orgs daily API limits?

Tags: lightning-web-components, governorlimits

I have been using uiRecordApi in my LWC components and I am wondering does it count towards my orgs daily API limits

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The uiRecordApi in Salesforce Lightning Web Components (LWC) is part of the **Lightning Data Service**, which handles data operations on the client side. These operations do not count against your org's daily API limits. Salesforce's API limits typically apply to server-side calls, such as those made using the **SOAP** and **REST APIs**. The `uiRecordApi` is designed to be efficient and reduce the need for explicit Apex server calls, thus conserving your API call limits for other integrations and services.

Comment: @TusharJadav thanks very much for answering, could you put your response as an answer I will make that a accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The `uiRecordApi` in Salesforce **Lightning Web Components** (LWC) is part of the **Lightning Data Service**, which handles data operations on the client side. These operations do not count against your org's daily API limits.

Salesforce's API limits typically apply to server-side calls, such as those made using the **SOAP** and **REST** **APIs**. The [`uiRecordApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-lightning-ui-api-record.html) is designed to be efficient and reduce the need for explicit Apex server calls, thus conserving your **API** call limits for other integrations and services.